# On Wireshark in Capture Options is it always just a line under Monitor Mode for interfaces?

Tags: networking, wireshark

I ran wireshark on my Mac and there is a checkbox in Capture Options for my interface under monitor mode.  I can check it and uncheck it.

When I run wireshark on ubuntu on the same wifi connection and I just have a line in that column.  Is that just how it is on ubuntu?  Is there a way to enable it like with the checkbox on my Mac?